# Does not contain a definition for GetIPv4Statistics

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip

I'm using the following line of code:

```
long br = NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
```

However, the `GetIPv4Statistics()` method is not recognised,

> 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetoworkInterface' does not contain a
>   definition for GetIPv4Statistics.

I've been looking through previous examples on the web and they work fine, according to the thread. What am I doing wrong, do I have to add a reference? 
All that am i doing is to measure the current download speed.

Comment: You sure you add `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace in _System.dll_?

Comment: yes, I have added the using System.Net.NetworkInformation; name space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetIPv4Statistics is a virtual method of an abstract class and cannot be called directly. You need an instance of a an object that inherits from NetworkInterface. Here's an example on how it can be used...

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces
    = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (var ni in interfaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived.ToString());
}
```